# Executing a program from Python 2.7.9 and measuring its performance

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance-testing

I'm trying to write a Python script that executes a program, and once the program terminates I'll have some performance data about it (average CPU and RAM consumption, and total run time).

From the research I've done, I learned that I can execute the program with subprocess.Popen(), and [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) lets me get performance data, but it appears that I only get whatever values are true at the moment of executing psutil's method, and not average values.

Also for the total run time, I couldn't find anything to help me with that, considering I'd like to run the program in the background while possibly executing another one.

Comment: Why don't you use an actual profiler?

Comment: It's a limitation with the testing framework at the moment. I understand I might not be able to reach the best results this way.